# How to create a list where every number shows twice?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created a word table.  I need to sort that table from time to time.

The table has 3 columns. the cells in the first columns are merged vertically for every two rows (in other words - the cells in the two other columns are split vertically - 2 rows 1 column)

I realized that merged cells can't be sorted. So I split all cells leaving other cell blank until i'll done with the sorting.

I have added another numbers' column so I can sort the table by numbers. I want the numbers' column to be an automatic list so It will be easier for me to add more rows and sort them in the table. But the problem is that the cells I have split and are now blank, and have to have the same number - each cell with the previous number from the cell above.

How do I create a list that counts every number twice?

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: example]

The  gridlines at the first 2 columns indicates the cells that were originally merged, and were split only in favor of the sorting.  Now I want to sort the table by the numbers in the first column in ascending order.

Comment: I'm pretty unclear as to what you're asking. Could you provide a graphical representation of what you have and what you want?

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0):

Try adding decimal values to the blank cells to keep everything arranged correctly when you sort, so the blank under 2 would be 2.1, etc.
Then modify the font so the color is the same as the background color, neatly hiding the text and keeping the appearance unchanged from the original.

Then, when you sort, those rows are put where they belong.